# emf direction in current loop, increasing flux

Tags: electromagnetism

Regarding this formula:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\Phi=-Emf$$

The electromotive force has a minus signal, indicating that it is created to oppose the change in flux through a surface. However, since emf is scalar, it's signal must be associated with a certain direction. If we imagine the situation of a current loop in the $xy$ plane, and a increasing magnetic field $\vec{B}$ in the positive $z$ direction. How to correctly represent the emf as a battery in the right direction? What is the positive orientation of the emf (if we think of it as a battery)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to compute the flux of $\vec B$ through the *open* surface $d\vec S$:
$$
\Phi=\oint_C \vec B\cdot d\vec S
$$
bounded by the circuit $C$, you need to assign a direction to $d\vec S$.  Thus is usually done by *assuming* the induced current in the loop circulates in one direction.  For a loop in the $z=0$ plane, going counterclockwise around the loop would define (assuming the loop is flat in the plane) $d\vec S= dS\hat z$.

If $-\frac{d}{dt}\oint_C \vec B\cdot d\vec S>0$, the emf is positive so the current circulate in the direction taken to define $d\vec S$ - in this case this would be counterclockwise.  If $-\frac{d}{dt}\oint_C \vec B\cdot d\vec S<0$ then the current will circulate in the opposite direction taken to define $d\vec S$ - in this case it would be the clockwise direction.

Comment: Thanks. When you say current, you mean conventional (positive charges)? If I represent the emf as a battery, supposing the inducted current (positive charges) flowing clockwise (for example), the battery orientation would be such that current hits the minus terminal and then the positive terminal, or the contrary?

Comment: @JoãoPedro of course I mean conventional current.